# Wiring a Ceiling fan with remote reciever and two wall switches

Tags: electrical

I bought a fan today, an upgraded version from what I have on another room. Wired it the same way as the other fan and I just blew the led light on the fan. The difference from old fan to the new one, is that the old one has halogen bulbs and the new one has LED light module. The receiver has Black and White coming into the receiver and Black, White and Blue coming out to the fan. On the old fan I connected the red wire together with both blue wires. I am able to turn the light on with wall switch and I can also control the light with the remote also. IF the light is on with the wall switch, I cannot turn it off with the remote.... but once I turn it off at the wall switch I an continue controlling it with the remote.

I tried to do the same with the LED fan light and it blew the light. Why would it work on one fan and not the other? What I am thinking is that the there is 110v coming from the black and 110v coming from the red and making the connection into a 220v. But if that is correct, why hasn't the other fan light blown already?

I am confused... I can only deduct that the LED light module cannot handle that amount of current. Can anyone explain and clarify this? Thank you

Comment: did you not follow the installation instructions?

Comment: I figured what happened. After removing the cover to remove the red wire and cap it.... I notice the blue wires came loose from the nut and grounded out on the metal case. Connected wire back with red wire and light is working with wall switch, but it seems the light part of the fan control module is damaged. Remote no longer controls the light, but just the fan. Before it was controlling both and also working with the light switch. Going to replace the remote control module. I had a little bit of a struggle putting the wire cover and I think it may have pulled the wires out.

Comment: The operation of the first sounds odd and wrong. Remote control should not rely on wall switch position to start. That's hokey...

Comment: I replaced the fan control module and decided not to take the risk of connecting the red wire to the blue wires. I went ahead and just capped it. I am certain the issue was a loose cap that caused the wires to ground. To be on the safe side, I  disconnected the red wire from the blue wires on the older fan as a precaution. The old fan was working, but did not want to take any chances.                                                                                                    I edited a wiring diagram and added the red wire the way I had it wired on the older fan. https://ibb.co/fYpZ8hP

Comment: I think that by connecting the red wire to both blue wires it was getting power from the black wire and the red wire at the same time..... which would make it a 240v source and destroy the fan. But I had the fan wired that way for many years and never had a problem. Can anyone look at the diagram and let me know why it was working and if its OK to wire it that way? https://ibb.co/fYpZ8hP

Comment: The old fan was working where I could turn on the light with the wall switch (Red Wire) independent of the other wall switch was on or off (Black Wire) and that's because the red wire was after the control module. If I turned both switches on, the remote could not turn off or dim the light, but if I switched the light red wire wall switch off, then I could control the light with the remote control.

Comment: What make and model is the new fan?